# 0x84BC0641 error in SQL SP3 installation

Tags: sql-server-2008, cmd, windows-server-2008-r2, caspol

I'm getting an error while installing SQL SP3 pack(Admin Mode) on Windows Server 2008 R2. Can someone provide the root cause of this error?

> using Silent installation
>   START /WAIT C:\Temp\SQLSP3.exe /QUIET /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ACTION=PATCH /ALLINSTANCES

[image]

Comment: Cleaned up the language a little bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following resolves this error code

Framework 4 no longer uses caspol.exe per running the command line:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727>caspol.exe -all -reset
```

Microsoft (R) .NET Framework CasPol 2.0.50727.5420
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

ERROR: Runtime error: This method explicitly uses CAS policy, which has been obs
oleted by the .NET Framework. In order to enable CAS policy for compatibility re
asons, please use the NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy configuration switch. 
Please
see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=155570 for more information.

Now I extracted the executable and the configuration file used for the setup seems to indicate that it is using the legacy flags indicated in the CAS link.

I ran the exact same command line on the 32 bit folder

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>caspol.exe -all -reset
```

And it successfully created security.config and security.config.cch in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config

Run the same command in Framework64 to generate security.config and security.comfig.cch files : C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\config

Answer (score 0):

You should try to
1. Download and install all available updates from Windows Update
2. Download and install all SP for Windows
3. Reinstall .net framework

Comment: What is the exact reason behind this error code ? is it because of corrupted .net security policy ?